# CanvasJS graph not been populated

Tags: jquery, json, canvasjs

I'm trying to populate a line chart (CanvasJS) with some data coming from a RESTful webservice.

The JSON array coming to me looks like:

```
[
[
    {
        "periodo": "2014-03-03",
        "quantidade": 2
    },
    {
        "periodo": "2014-09-13",
        "quantidade": 1
    },
    {
        "periodo": "2015-06-23",
        "quantidade": 6
    },
    {
        "periodo": "2015-06-24",
        "quantidade": 2
    },
    {
        "periodo": "2015-06-25",
        "quantidade": 1
    }
],
[
    {
        "periodo": "2015-06-23",
        "quantidade": 1
    }
]
]
```

i.e., two arrays (that I want to transform in two lines in graph). In my jQuery code, I'm adding some proprieties to this JSON array, like this:

```
var chartdata = [];

jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {     
   var chart = {};
   chart["type"] =          "spline";
   chart["showInLegend"] =  true;
   chart["dataPoints"] =    val;
   chartdata.push(chart);
});
```

And finally I'm calling the drawer:

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
            animationEnabled: true,
            zoomEnabled: true,
            data: chartdata,
            legend: {
                cursor: "pointer",
                itemclick: function (e) {
                    if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                        e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                    } else {
                        e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                }
                chart.render();
                }
            }
        });
```

But the graph is not being drawn. There's no error either. I compare my final JSON array and it's pretty similar to the one in the [CanvasJS example](http://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=http://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/overview/multiSeries-spline-chart/)

Where am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It look like your chart.render() is only in the legend object.
Try putting it after creating the chart object (see below).

I hope this helps.
Mat

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
    animationEnabled: true,
    zoomEnabled: true,
    data: chartdata,
    legend: {
        cursor: "pointer",
        itemclick: function (e) {
            if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                e.dataSeries.visible = false;
            } else {
                e.dataSeries.visible = true;
            }
            chart.render();
        }
    }
});
chart.render();
```